How to send the name of the person who edits the form in sharepoint using powerapss?
I am currently editing a form in PowerApss based on a previously created sharepoint list, I have a field of type "Person or group" for the column "Owner".
The idea is that the name of the person is automatically assigned to this change to avoid information impersonation...
I was trying to manage from powerapps putting as default value User().FullName but I get error.
Do you think it is feasible to create a flow from power Automate to perform this action or is it possible from the configuration of the list or the powerApps where is the form?
Thank you very much
I was trying to manage from powerapps putting as default value User().FullName but I get error.

The SharePoint person field is an object and requires a more complex input than just the user full name.
You can use this as the default value in the control, not the card.
{ 
  DisplayName:User().FullName,
  Claims:"i:0#.f|membership|" & Lower(User().Email), 
  Department:"",  
  Email:User().Email, 
  JobTitle:"", 
  Picture:""
}


If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

thanks for the answer, but when I put the answer in the datacardvalue I get an error, I don't know why, it says: "User().FullName: There is an error in this formula. Check it again and run it again".
